Seemingly identical text but different bytes in R
I am running into a problem where I have seemingly identical text, but the underlying bytes are different. See this code and the output as printed in the console:
---
**'text':**
> text <- qdf$Question_text[[12]]

> text

[1] "Het liefst zou ikâ€¦"

> charToRaw(text)

 [1] 48 65 74 20 6c 69 65 66 73 74 20 7a 6f 75 20 69 6b c3 a2 e2 82 ac c2 a6

---

**'text2':**
> text2 <- "Het liefst zou ikâ€¦"

> text2

[1] "Het liefst zou ikâ€¦"
> charToRaw(text2)


 [1] 48 65 74 20 6c 69 65 66 73 74 20 7a 6f 75 20 69 6b e2 80 a6

---

As you can see, text and text2 are printed identically in the console. Yet the underlying bytes are different. 'text' is set from an object; 'text2' is set from a string which I define in the R script.
My main question is: why are these objects different, and how can I get 'text' to be like 'text2'?
Further information: 'text2' can be properly converted using iconv(., from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8"); so that the special horizontal ellipsis shows properly. For 'text', that does not work.
---

> clean <- iconv(text, from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")

> clean

[1] "Het liefst zou ikâ€¦"

> clean2 <- iconv(text2, from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")

> clean2

[1] "Het liefst zou ik…"


---

I have tried various conversions and a wide range of encodings for 'text'. It seems to be UTF-8, but with these bytes a proper conversion does not seem possible.
These are the set encodings of the two text objects (setting the encoding of 'text' to 'latin1' did not help for the conversion):
> Encoding(text)
[1] "UTF-8"
> Encoding(text2)
[1] "latin1"

Version info:

R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 

RStudio
2022.02.1 Build 461


Update 20/6/2024: with help of user2554330 I solved this issue like this:
text <- qdf$Question_text[[12]]
text
 [1] "Het liefst zou ikâ€¦"
charToRaw(text)
 [1] 48 65 74 20 6c 69 65 66 73 74 20 7a 6f 75 20 69 6b c3 a2 e2 82 ac c2 a6

text_fix_step1 <- iconv(text, from = "UTF-8", to = "WINDOWS-1252")
Encoding(text_fix_step1) <- "UTF-8"
charToRaw(text_fix_step1)
 [1] 48 65 74 20 6c 69 65 66 73 74 20 7a 6f 75 20 69 6b e2 80 a6

text_fixed <- iconv(text_fix_step1, from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")
text_fixed
[1] "Het liefst zou ik…"


One difference is the one you saw:
> Encoding(text)
[1] "UTF-8"
> Encoding(text2)
[1] "latin1"

However, your manipulation
> clean2 <- iconv(text2, from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")

> clean2

[1] "Het liefst zou ik…"

suggests that there is something wrong with text.  I would guess the following sequence happened:

it was originally the same as clean2 in UTF-8,
then the encoding got incorrectly changed to "latin1" or some Windows encoding, so the multibyte character "…" was interpreted as the three characters "â€¦",
then it was converted to UTF-8 again, converting each of those characters
into the multibyte UTF-8 equivalent.

Undoing sequences like that is hard, but I think this might do it:
 step3 <- text
 step2 <- iconv(step3, to = "WINDOWS-1252")
 step1 <- step2
 Encoding(step1) <- "utf8"

It doesn't work on my system where UTF-8 is the native encoding, but it might work on yours, where I'm guessing Windows-1252 is the native encoding.
The key things to remember:

R only supports 2 or 3 encodings for display:  "latin1", "UTF-8", and "unknown", which means "the native encoding".
Assigning to Encoding(text) doesn't change the bytes, it just changes the label, so the bytes are interpreted differently.
iconv() changes the bytes.  Since not all UTF-8 strings are representable in single byte encodings, there are options for how to handle the problematic characters.


Thank you very much! With this I solved the issue. This will save me alot of work manually replacing the erroneous bytes.
